# Issue trying to access tomcat from another computer inside my office network

Tags: tomcat

I'm facing a problem trying to access my tomcat installation from another computer inside my office network.

I've read over internet (even here at Stack) about this problem, but I still not found a solution. From the other computer (Lets call it Computer B) I'm trying to access using http://ComputerA:8080. I've checked that the firewall isn't blocking that port and actually, just to make a test, I've pointed an installation of a WAMP Server to that port, and I can access from the computer B, so it seems that isn't a port problem (or blocked by a firewall).

The weird thing is that I've made a ping from B to A, but there was no response, even if I'm actually got connection to the WAMP pointing to port 8080. Seems that is a problem with Tomcat.

So, I've been trying for hours but I don't know how to solve my problem.

Any help from you would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing I'd try is attempting to access the site from the machine itself using the URL:

```
http://ComputerA:8080
```

Its possible you only have Tomcat listening on the loopback (This is controlled in the server.xml [See](https://cgsrv1.arrc.csiro.au/blog/2009/07/10/tomcat-listen-only-on-localhost/))

Since Windows Firewall does often provide or block access based on application, not just port, your test with WAMP might not be exactly perfect, but its an okay test. A better test would be to temporarily completely disable your firewall:

e.g. Running the following as an Administrator Command Shell:

```
netsh firewall set opmode mode = disable
```

Assuming neither of the above let you see what is going on, I'd then try the IP address of the host rather than the name. I'd expect your WAMP test to fail if the WINS name was not resolving correctly, but using the IP at least carves out a few other possible issues.